# How to know OPC job status using Syncsort or anyother method?

Tags: mainframe, jcl

My objective is, I need to get the current timestamp using Syncsort if one OPC job(existing Job) run fine in production. In my case I can not interpret my new job after existing OPC job. Is there any facility to check the existing job ran fine in production ?
I mean any reference table to have production job details with status for each day ?

Please help anyone to move.

Comment: Can you re-word "interpret my new job" as it is unclear what you mean by this. We don't know anything about your site set-up. Have you talked to your support groups? There is nothing standard for what you seem to want in the OS, but OPC itself will definitely know if a JOB worked. What "timestamp" and what do you mean by "current"?

Answer (score 0):

There are commercial packages that track jobs and job status.  CA (computer associates) is one such vendor.

However, these packages cost a lot.  A simple, home grown solution, is to have a dataset known to both jobs and write a one line record into that data set when job1 completes and the second job2 can read the dataset to "KNOW" if the job ran.  IF this is what you are trying to do, it is not exactly clear from your question.  But any solution along these lines works, until management wants to cough up $50K (or whatever) for a commercial package.

Comment: They already have a commercial package, OPC is  part of Tivoli Workload Scheduler. All OP has to do is actually work out what they want and ask the techies responsible for OPC/TWS.